# Return the estimate y value for a certain x value. Using dataframe, scatterplot, statsmodels

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics

I'm looking for: "an estimate of the muscle mass for a women aged 60 years" from a graph that I produced with the following code:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
model = ols('y ~ x', data).fit()
print(model.summary())

a1 = model.params[1]
print('a1 (slope) = {:.4f}'.format(a1))
a0 = model.params[0]
print('a0 (intercept) = {:.4f}'.format(a0))

#line of regression
def y_model(x):
    return a0 + a1*x

# now plot the regressed line as a function of the input data x
plt.plot(x, y_model(x), label='least-squares fit')
# plot the original data
plt.plot(x, y,'ro', label='original data')
plt.xlabel('age, years')
plt.ylabel('muscle mass')
plt.title('Muscle Mass in Women Ages 40-79' )
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

If possible, I want to use the a function from model. Even if I can figure out a way to return the y values where x ==60, how would I make that an 'estimate'? Should I take an average?

[image: Here is a picture of the graph]

Answer (score 1):

The model object has a "predict" method that you can use. If the model has not yet been fit, params is not optional, but if it is fitted params are saved in the model instance.
Read here:
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict

You do basically:
y_new = model.predict(new_sample)